# simple-react-validator throws error for all required fields after resetting them upon submit

Tags: reactjs, validation

#### Problem

I am using `simple-react-validator` for all my form validations.
I had faced an issue where I wanted to reset all my fields after sending data to the API but `simple-react-validtor` threw errors for all the "required" but emptied fields, which I did not wanted. There was nothing in the docs about it.

#### What I had tried:

I had put `validator.hideMessages()` just after resetting but it was not working. I think this happened because soon after resetting the fields, re-rendering would take place causing the `simple-react-validtor` to show error for all the fields.

```js
const handleAdd = () => {
  const data = pick(transactionCharges, [
    "CommissionCharge",
    "CurrencyId",
    "UserId",
    // ...
  ]);

  if (validator.allValid()) {
    // Send data
    props.addCharges(data).then(() => {
      loadTableData();
      setTransactionCharges(_initialFormFields); // Reset
      validator.hideMessages();
    });
  } else {
    validator.showMessages();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [issue/solution](https://github.com/dockwa/simple-react-validator/issues/132). I cannot say that this is the right approach, but it worked for me!

#### My fix was:

```js
const handleAdd = () => {
  const data = pick(transactionCharges, [
    "CommissionCharge",
    "CurrencyId",
    "UserId",
    // ...
  ]);

  if (validator.allValid()) {
    // Send data
    props.addCharges(data).then(() => {
      loadTableData();
      setTransactionCharges(_initialFormFields); // Reset
      validator.visibleFields = [];              // Fix 1
      forceUpdate();                             // Fix 2
    });
  } else {
    validator.showMessages();
  }
};
```